# Move Menu Bar to Bottom + Make Sticky / Angular UI Problem

Tags: html, css, angular, user-interface, angular-material

On Angular UI one page app, there is an overhead menu, side bar menu, and I am trying to implement a bottom menu bar.

In the component itself I have it as position: sticky:

```
@import '../../../styles/variables';

.bottom-bar {
  position: sticky;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 65px;
  width: absolute;
}


.menu-button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  &__text {
    font-family: $font-sarabun, 'sans-serif';
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;

    @media (max-width: 992px) {
      display: none;
    }
  }
}

.mat-button,
.mat-icon-button,
.mat-stroked-button {
    color: inherit;
    background: 0 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    vertical-align: 0px;
}

.menu-button-import {
    margin-top: 15px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: $color-menu-item;
    font-weight: 500;
    min-width: 100px;
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius: 5px;

    &__text {
    font-family: $font-sarabun, 'sans-serif';
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;

    @media (max-width: 992px) {
      display: none;
    }
  }
  }

.menu-button-save {
    margin-top: 8px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: $color-menu-item;
    font-weight: 500;
    min-width: 100px;
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }


.menu-button-export {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    background-color: #0693e3;
    font-weight: 500;
    min-width: 100px;
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;

  &__icon {
    color: white;
  }

  }
```

In the app html the bottom-bar component is also sticky:

```
.bottom-bar{
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
}
```

However, when I run the app I am having to scroll down to see the bottom bar. When I zoom out I notice that the bottom bar is not at the bottom of the page.

I am trying to make it so that the bottom bar stays fixed at the bottom of the page even when scrolling.

Hopefully I described the problem clearly enough. Please advise on how I can fix the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Show your complete code + a image what you want to have.

Comment: Can't show much because it's for my company.

Comment: A simple bottom bar with a menu? I don't ask for the complete application code.

Comment: Added CSS for the bottom bar. It's supposed to look like a bottom bar pane that stays in the same place even when scrolling.

Comment: use `position: fixed;`

Comment: I did that and the bottom bar moved up to near the top of the page and instead of being horizonal it flipped vertical. Now I think it's an issue with the position of the component on the app html page...

Comment: Something like that? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fixed-footer-header?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: Yes, I need it to be just like the "footer" element that stays in the same place when scrolling.

Comment: Okay, the bottom bar is behaving as intended, but it is in the wrong place. I need to have it be stuck at the bottom of the screen but it's near the top.